# laravel 4.2 generate web views and REST calls from the same logic

Tags: php, rest, mobile, laravel-4.2

I am using laravel 4.2 in my web application with the normal way to generate html views .. i want to perform REST calls to new routes that use the same logic in my controllers functions (which returns html views) .. what is the best technique to do this? .. how to make the same function serve both web and mobile app (through REST API).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Request::wantsJson()` method as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#request-information).

```
if (Request::wantsJson()) {
    // Perform REST API stuff here
}
else {
    // Normal requests / returning views here
}
```